# How can i pass the timestamp with my Ajax.actionlink

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

i have the folloiwng Index view that show a list of objects and a Delete Ajax.actionlink beside each object:-

```
<legend>@Model.Where(d => d.VisitStatu.Description.ToUpper().Equals("ASSINGED")).Count() @ViewBag.subtitle</legend>
<table>
    <tr>   
        <th>Patient Full Name </th>

         <th>Created BY</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Where(d => d.VisitStatu.Description.ToUpper().Equals("ASSINGED")))
{
    <tr id = @item.VisitID>           
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Patient.FullName)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy)</td>
        <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",
       "Delete", "Visit",
      new { id = item.VisitID },
    new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    OnSuccess = "deletionconfirmation",
    OnFailure = "deletionerror"
}
</td>  </tr>
```

where the Ajax.actionlink will call the following Post Action Method:-

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {            try
            {  var v = repository.GetVisit(id);
                if (!(v.Editable(User.Identity.Name)))
                {return View("NotFound");                }
                repository.DeleteVisit(v);
                repository.Save();
return Json(new { IsSuccess = "True", id = id, description = v.Date.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
return Json(new { IsSuccess = "False" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
            {
                return Json(new { IsSuccess = "False" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }}
```

But currently if the user clicks on the Delete link and the record was modified by another user then no `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` will be raised ,, as i am not passing the timestamp to the delete action method... so how i can include the timestamp values with the Delete ajax.actionlink?
//Hint the object already include a timestamp propert.
BR

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it as query string parameter, the same way you are passing the id:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Delete",
    "Delete", 
    "Visit",
    new { 
        id = item.VisitID,
        timestamp = item.Timestamp
    },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        OnSuccess = "deletionconfirmation",
        OnFailure = "deletionerror"
    }
)
```

and then have the Delete controller action take a `timestamp` parameter.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how i can then tell the Post action method to include the timestamp in the delete request sent to the database?

Comment: @johnG, this question has no longer any relation to ASP.NET MVC. Please start a new thread where you explain your database structure, the data access technology you are using, if you are using an ORM such as EF show your model classes ...